# What does injecting a service to app.module's constructor do?

Tags: angular

I'm using the SmartAdmin theme and they have injected `app.service` into  `app.module`.

Have been trying to find out the purpose of this injection but didn't come across anyone doing this. The closest is providing `AppState` as a provider in `app.module`, which I know is so that only a single instance will be used throughout the whole app.

Can someone shed some light on what this statement does in `app.module`? And how should I be using it?

```js
export class AppModule {
  constructor(public appRef: ApplicationRef, public appState: AppState) {}
}
```

Here's the content for `AppState`:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

export type InternalStateType = {
  [key: string]: any
};

@Injectable()
export class AppState {
  _state: InternalStateType = { };

  constructor() {

  }

  // already return a clone of the current state
  get state() {
    return this._state = this._clone(this._state);
  }
  // never allow mutation
  set state(value) {
    throw new Error('do not mutate the `.state` directly');
  }


  get(prop?: any) {
    // use our state getter for the clone
    const state = this.state;
    return state.hasOwnProperty(prop) ? state[prop] : state;
  }

  set(prop: string, value: any) {
    // internally mutate our state
    return this._state[prop] = value;
  }


  private _clone(object: InternalStateType) {
    // simple object clone
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify( object ));
  }
}
```

Comment: _on what this statement does_ - what statement?

Comment: I i think it use the IMMUTABLE PATTERN (like Reflux and so on) .. so it clone your states ...could it be?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. Could you please clarify the question?

Comment: He's asking what's the reason of injecting `AppState` in `AppModule`, and now that I'm thinking about it, I'm not really sure what's the use of that...

Comment: I've never come across any form of injection in `modules` in the constructor before. Hence I'm not sure what's the reason for the theme to do that, and it there's any design pattern or technical reasons behind it.